# Can anamurminers.com be trusted?

Tags: mining-hardware, fraud

I'm thinking about ordering two 63 GH/s Bitcoin miner's from Anamurminers.com Also see: http://anamurminers.com/asic-miner. Can this company be trusted? They say they can ship two to the UK straight away.

Answer (score 6):

There's no way this is legitimate.

- Domain is less than a month old
- All product photos can be found elsewhere on the web. http://www.stss.ru/products/workstations/tesla/RX240T8.2.html http://www.fractal-design.com/?view=product&prod=94
- Address/phone number/name on Contact Us page differs from address/phone number/name on WHOIS record.
- They say their miner connects over USB. However, they don't have any drivers for it on their website, or say what OS it works with.
- They said that they're too busy to take a video, or post an non stock-photo image, but they would in a week. They said that 10 days ago.
- They [claimed](http://anamurminers.com/index.php?route=information/information&information_id=4) that they designed, wrote, sourced, soldered, and tested the whole thing, front to back, in 3 weeks. Then somebody on bitcointalk pointed that out, and now it took them 3 months! Still implausible, though. Unless you're willing to pay insane markups, your shortest turnaround time on an ASIC is around 6 months, and that's if you already have your design done.
- They offer local pickup (in the Czech Republic)
- This gem:

  > Due to Czech law, we MUST, give you back your money even after 14 days, if you are not satisfied with the product.

  I doubt that.

So yeah. Scam. I'm guessing that Antonio Barreto is the brains of the operation, and Anamur Silif is the fall guy.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly nobody except the owner or local auditors can tell you if its a scam, all you can do is gather as much information as possible. **Maybe the only real deal would be to visit the company locally or get documents that proof what they claim**.

Concerning the website, its a very basic opencart shop one can setup in 30 minutes.

Below is what i got on a fast search.

> Information about us
>
> www.anamurminers.com is a site operated by **Anamur Silif, s.r.o.**
>   ("We"); we are a company registered in Czech republic under
>   registration number **241 65 280**. Our registered office is Primátorská
>   296/38, Prague 8   180 00.

#

> The domain/hosting whois reveals:   Email Search: is associated with
>   about 213,056 domains NS History: 3 changes on 4 unique name servers
>   over 0 year. IP History: 3 changes on 4 unique IP addresses over 0
>   years. Whois History: 13 records have been archived since 2013-05-04 .
>   Reverse IP: 629 other sites hosted on this server. Log In or Create a
>   FREE account to start monitoring this domain name Preview the complete
>   Domain Report for anamurminers.com
>
> Registrant:  Anamur Silif s.r.o.  Kasparova 590  Liberec,  46312  CZ
>
> Domain name: ANAMURMINERS.COM
>
> Administrative Contact:
>       Barreto, Antonio Joaquin
>       Kasparova 590
>       Liberec,  46312
>       CZ
>       +420.774984192    Fax: +420.000000000
>
> Technical Contact:
>       a.s., INTERNET CZ
>       Ktis 2
>       Ktis,  384 03
>       CZ
>       +420.383835353    Fax: +420.383835354
>
> Registration Service Provider:
>       INTERNET CZ, a.s., 
>       00420-38-3835353
>
> Registrar of Record: TUCOWS, INC.  Record last updated on
>   10-May-2013.  Record expires on 30-Apr-2014.  Record created on
>   30-Apr-2013.
>
> Registrar Domain Name Help Center:
>       http://tucowsdomains.com
>
> Domain servers in listed order:
>       NS2.GOSHAWK.ARVIXE.COM
>       NS1.GOSHAWK.ARVIXE.COM
>
> Domain status: clientTransferProhibited
>                   clientUpdateProhibited

#

> Google search on **Anamur Silif, s.r.o**
>   https://www.google.com/search?q=Anamur+Silif%2C+s.r.o&ie=UTF-8&sa=Search&channel=fe&client=browser-ubuntu&hl=en

#

> More lookups:
>
> 1. http://rejstrik.penize.cz/24165280-anamur-silif-s-r-o
> 2. http://www.bizbiz.cz/v2/firmy/239749/anamur-silif-s-r-o
> 3. http://topkontakt.idnes.cz/f/anamur-silif-s-r-o/1945713/

Answer (score -2):

seems like they are also discussed here: 
http://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=233346.0